# Creating a table having a group of attributes with same name

Tags: sql, database-design

I am actually trying to create a student database and I need my table to be something of this type

[image: a picture of what i am expecting]

In the above picture the date is something like a super-column name to columns-A,B,C,D which are subject names.
My data will be inserted in those A,B,C,D columns.

My final aim is to access attendance in all subjects based on the date.

Something like:-

```
       select 27-01-2020 from 'table-name';
```

the above query should give me the attendance in all subjects on 27-01-2020 date

Is there any way to create such a table or similar to this one?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you would like to do. Please, try to write more and be more explicit rather than implicit with the descriptions. Also, try to comment on what your current situation is and what you would like to achieve

Comment: My final aim is to access the attendance of all the subjects based on the date

Comment: You can't. What you can do is add another column for date and then filter using `select * from your_table where date='2020-01-27'`

Comment: In database you don't have something similar to what you refer as a super-column, the closest thing you can do is to create two tables:
the first will contain a list of dates, 
the second one will be your table plus the date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a table for the students and a table for the subjects, you could use a third table, representing the attendance of the students to the different subjects.

Such table will have a date, a reference to the subject, a reference to the student and an attendance column, possibly of type boolean, denoting if the student was present during that day at that subject. You may also add a slot, in case there are more than one hour of lecture for a subject on that day (but this is up to you and your needs).

There should also be a uniqueness constraint on the tuple (date, student, subject), so that there cannot be a student present at two different lectures the same day (unless you use the slot, to which the uniqueness constraint should also span).

Comment: Wont the third table be very huge. Number of students is like 50 and attendance in 5 subjects for 90 days

Comment: If it's just for 90 days, then you will have 90 * 50 * 5 = 22500 records (or rows). Databases can handle such many rows. Indeed, they can handle millions of rows per table. The problem is, aren't you using the wrong tool? A database may be an overkill, especially if it's just a temporary thing and you need to learn how to setup and model a database.